# UIImage from array with URL

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uiimageview

i currently developping an app which retrieve url from JSON, and create some ImageView with the URLS.
When i decode my JSON, i stock every URL into an array.

The problem is, how can i create an ImageView for each URLS which are in my array ?

This is my code :

```
if(success == 1)
            {
         DataFromJSon = jsonData["objects"] as! NSArray

         repos.removeAll()

         for one in DataFromJSon {
         let repo = Repository(jsonData: one as! [String : AnyObject])
         repos.append(repo)

                }

                for repo in repos {
                    lines.insert(repo.picture_url, atIndex: i)
                    dump(lines)
                    i++
                }


             //Construct the imgUrl to get an image URL for the pages
                if let urlString: NSString = MyArray {
                    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString as String) {
                        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                            newCard.image = UIImage(data: data)!
                            newCard.content = titleApp
                            newCard.desc = prixApp
                            self.data.append(newCard)
                            NSLog("fetch new data")
                        }
                    }
                }
             }
```

Thank you !

Watch out :

[image: GIF Swype]

Comment: Please tell me you aren't running `if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)` on the main thread?

Comment: effectivly i use it on the main thread, at least, i think, what is the problem ?

Comment: You're running a long running process on the main thread, which blocks the main thread and makes your UI unresponsive. Network operations are usually performed on a background thread for this reason.

Comment: hum yes i understand,  you're right , i use this function but in another thread in one of my other class. But it's not very important here, my app is not in prod , it's just for test, but thank for your advise :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimum working example

```
var urls = [NSURL]()
urls.append(NSURL(string: "https://yourimage1")!)
urls.append(NSURL(string: "https://yourimage2")!)

for url in urls {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
            let image = UIImage(data: data)!
            let view = UIImageView(image: image)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                // Display your view here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As referred to by @Abizern, you should put the downloading of the data in a background queue, and use the main queue for updating the UI. You can scale the image by setting the size of the UIImageView and then using `.ScaleAspectFit` or `.ScaleAspectFill` on the contentMode property according to your needs.

**Edit**

I just tested it with the imagelinks you provided, and the code works fine.

```
    var urls = [NSURL]()
    urls.append(NSURL(string: "http://www.parkers.co.uk/Images/PageFiles/74655/firstdrive9.jpg")!)
    urls.append(NSURL(string: "http://www.rsiauto.fr/images/BMW/330-Ci/330-Ci-1.jpg")!)

    var i = 0
    let width = self.view.frame.width/2
    let height = self.view.frame.height

    for url in urls {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)!
                let frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(i++)*width, 0, width, height)
                i++
                let view = UIImageView(image: image)
                view.frame = frame
                view.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
                view.layer.masksToBounds = true
                view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.view.addSubview(view)
                    print("Done")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here a screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: hello, thanks for the code, i already change my code to make network operation in a background queue. MoreoverI tried your solution but it doesn't work, i get 2 images view but with the same picture .

Comment: What do you mean with the same picture? Are placing them on a UIView to display?

Comment: Take a look at my edited post. It's always the same picture which is shown, instead of theses : http://www.rsiauto.fr/images/BMW/330-Ci/330-Ci-1.jpg ; http://www.parkers.co.uk/Images/PageFiles/74655/firstdrive9.jpg

Comment: But have you seen the GIF ? i try to implement the "Swype gesture", by the way, i can not use the subView. For each image i call the model "NewCard.image". I think the loop fail because sometime i success to show the 2 differents pictures but sometimes no.

Comment: if newcard is always the same instance when you are assigning, then of course when your are setting the image it will be overwritten every time.

Comment: Yeah i'm going to explore this way , i will try to delete the first line of my array, after the NewCard appears, by the way , when my function will read into my array, it will take the next URL. Do you think it's good ?

Comment: Why don't you create the newCard object right within the loop, and then add it to the array?